# Prevent KeywordTokenizer from creating multiple key-value pairs

Tags: lucene

I use the Lucene java `QueryParser` with `KeywordAnalyzer`. A query like `topic:(hello world)` is broken up in to multiple parts by the `KeywordTokenizer` so the resulting Query object looks like this `topic:(hello) topic:(world)` i.e. Instead of one, I now have two key-value pairs. I would like the `QueryParser` to interpret `hello world` as one value, without using double quotes. What is the best way to do so?

Parsing `topic:("hello world")` results in a single key value combination but, using double quotes is not an option.

I am not using the Lucene search engine. I am using Lucene's QueryParser just for parsing the query, not for searching. The text `Hello World` is entered at runtime, by the user so that can change. I would like `KeywordTokenizer` to treat `Hello World` as one Token instead of parsing splitting it in to two Tokens.

Comment: Could you please add a code snippet specifying how you call the query parser? I believe you can write a custom query parser yourself or add the quotes as a preprocessing stage. If not, please explain why this is not so.

Comment: QueryParser qp = new QueryParser("unknown", new KeywordAnalyzer());
qp.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.AND_OPERATOR);
Query query = qp.parse(aString);

aString comes from the user of the web application.

If aString is topic:(hello world) then, I get two Terms like topic:hello topic:world

Comment: The user of my web application can enclose aString in double quotes like this topic:("hello world"). That would give me one Term object to work with instead of two. But that Term is not perfect. It automatically chops off the double quotes and the resulting key:value will look like topic:hello world without the double quotes. I do not want the Query Parser to remove double quotes entered by the user because my non-Lucene search engine relies on these double quotes to perform an exact phrase search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a [BooleanQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_1/api/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html). Here's a code snippet using the .NET port of Lucene. This should work with both the KeywordAnalyzer and the StandardAnalyzer.

```
var luceneAnalyzer = new KeywordAnalyzer();

var query1 = new QueryParser("Topic", luceneAnalyzer).Parse("hello");
var query2 = new QueryParser("Topic", luceneAnalyzer).Parse("world");

BooleanQuery filterQuery = new BooleanQuery();
filterQuery.Add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
filterQuery.Add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

TopDocs results = searcher.Search(filterQuery);
```

Comment: I am not using the Lucene search engine. I am using Lucene's QueryParser just for parsing the query, not for searching. The text hello world is entered at runtime, by the user so that can change. I just want KeywordTokenizer to treat Hello World as one Token instead of parsing splitting it in to two Tokens.

Comment: Does not exactly answer the question but I am selecting it because of the beautiful description and working code that you have provided. It should help others getting started with Lucene Query Parser.

Comment: Would be better if you accepted an answer to the question - I just got confused!

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the query directly as follows. This preserves the space.

```
Query query = new TermQuery(new Term("field", "value has space"));
```

If you print query as `System.out.println(query);` you will see the following result.

```
field:value has space
```

Comment: Thanks. This is not quite what I need.